# Stuck in a loop after invalid input

Tags: c++

My question: This code works one time through. If input in valid it proceeds to the next cout "input number of attackers." If the input is invalid the error message appears "Number must be 1 through 5", but it gets stuck in a loop there repeating "Choose your attacking animal". Regardless of input after that it repeats the same. How do I get it to continue after that if the input is valid?

```
bool validInput = true;
do
{
    cout << "Choose your attacking animal:" << endl;
    cout << "1 = Bunny, 2 = Chicken, 3 = Kitty, 4 = Puppy, 5 = Wolverine" << endl;
    cin >> attacker;

    if (attacker < 1 || attacker > 5 || cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Number must be 1 through 5" << endl;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        validInput = false;
    }
} while (!validInput);

cout << "Choose how many " << attacker<< " are attacking"<<endl;
cin >> attNum;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because after you set validInput to false in the first run of the loop with an invalid input, there is no code to set it to true in other attempts, hece going into an infinite loop, i.e. the while condition always fails.

What you need to do is set valdInput to true when the answer is within the valid expected values. For instance, modifying your original code:

```
bool validInput = true;
    do
{
            cout << "Choose your attacking animal:" << endl;
    cout << "1 = Bunny, 2 = Chicken, 3 = Kitty, 4 = Puppy, 5 = Wolverine" <<          endl;
    cin >> attacker;

    if (attacker < 1 || attacker > 5 || cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Number must be 1 through 5" << endl;

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        validInput = false;
    } else {
        validInput = true;
    }
} while (!validInput);

cout << "Choose how many " << attacker<< " are attacking"<<endl;
cin >> attNum;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You set validInput to false, when it fails, but you never set validInput to true, when the input is, in fact, valid.

Just add an else block to your if block, setting validInput to true.

Answer (score 2):

As LarsEggert already stated you never set back back the valid-flag to true if the input was in fact valid.

I would solve it in the following way:

```
bool validInput;
do {
  // Assumption: Input will be valid (Loop will not repeat in this case)
  validInput = true;
  cout << "Choose your attacking animal:" << endl;
  cout << "1 = Bunny, 2 = Chicken, 3 = Kitty, 4 = Puppy, 5 = Wolverine" << endl;
  cin >> attacker;

  // Check if assumption was wrong (Loop will run again in this case)
  if (attacker < 1 || attacker > 5 || cin.fail())
  {
    cout << "Number must be 1 through 5" << endl;

    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
    validInput = false;
  }
} while (!validInput);

cout << "Choose how many " << attacker<< " are attacking"<<endl;
cin >> attNum;
```

In compare to Jorge Torres's answer you won't have to write the else-case.

I typically follow this form for loops:

```
bool repeat;
do {
  repeat = false

  // do something
  // if loop has to be repeated, just set repeat = true somewhere here
} while(repeat);
```

This way you don't have a negation in your while and you also just have to focus on the cases where the repeat-flag has to be set.

Comment: I think writing an else case is better. Less chance of bugs than when you leave bools around with arbitrary 'defaults'

Answer (score 1):

It's because if the input is wrong, it's not extracted and removed from the input buffer, and since you call [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) without argument you only extract a single character from the invalid input, and if there's more invalid input after that then your next input will read that.

You could use [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to extract (and discard) input until the next newline like this:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: This is indeed _a_ bug. One he's not asking about, but a bug nonetheless.